# Why is there no intellisense in ASP.Net MVC 2.0 when assigning Model values to JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, intellisense

I'm trying to add some Model properties into my JavaScript within my content page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    createPager(1, <%=Model.TotalPages %>);
    createUnprocessedPager(1, <%=Model.TotalUnprocessedPages %>);
});
```

Does anyone know if this is by design? Are you not meant to combine Model properties with JavaScript? Or is this a bug?

This works as expected. However, I do not have any Intellisense within the `<% ... %>` tags when actually writing the code. If I write any code within `<script>` tags, then there's no Intellisense. If I go directly under the tag `</script>` and type `<% Model.... %>` then *boom*, I have Intellisense again.

**UPDATE: 22/10/2010**

Just read [Scott Guthrie's latest blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx) and it appears this functionality is coming out soon with the up coming release of ASP.Net MVC 3 (possibly for the beta as well):

> Note: Visual Studio Code/Markup
>   Intellisense and Colorization within
>   Razor files aren’t enabled yet with
>   the Beta earlier this month.  You’ll
>   see this show up in a few weeks though
>   – and it will support full code
>   intellisense for HTML, JavaScript, CSS
>   and C#/VB code within Razor files.

Comment: This might not be very helpful, but ... it works with resharper ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will loose you Intellisense in the views inside quotes "" like attributes.

```
<input type="text" value="<%= DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>" />
```

or if it appears inside of Javascript blocks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>
    </script>
```

It is my opinion that there should be Intellisense in these scenarios, so I would say it is a bug and hope future updates to Visual Studio will address and resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

There is also no syntax highlighting I think. Not sure if that's a bug or a feature, but AFAIK, combining the code this way isn't a good practice. Generally inline javascript is not a good practice, but if you go with it, combine Model properties with it, and later decide to extract the scripts into a separate js file, your code will break. Therefore, it is quite common to populate hidden fields with your Model properties and read them in your js with jQuery, e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" id="valTotalPages" value="<%=Model.TotalPages %>" />
<input type="hidden" id="valTotalUnprocessedPages" value="<%=Model.TotalUnprocessedPages %>" />

... 

// in js
$(document).ready(function () {
    createPager(1, $("#valTotalPages").val());
    createUnprocessedPager(1, $("#valTotalUnprocessedPages").val());
});
```

So lack of syntax highlighting and intellisense might be a bug, but might as well be a way of discouraging certain code patterns.

Comment: Note: you will still lose intellisense when you do `value="<%=Model.TotalPages %>"`. This happens whenever you wrap `<% %>` in quotes.

Comment: Any way around it? Or is it a case of getting a visual studios plugin?

Comment: introducing extract hidden fields is not a good practice. it increases page size. I would rather live with no Intellisense .vote down.

Comment: @Russel Yang: It's not just an intellisense issue. How would you access the value from an external js file otherwise?

Comment: @Russel: Yakimych is right. You don't want to introduce globals do you? I know don't because sooner or later someone else might use the same names as well.

Comment: @Russel Yang: This technique might actually reducing the total download size because you're moving the javascript out of the page and into a cacheable external js file.

Comment: I agree with @Russel.  @Yakimych - you don't need to introduce globals, use namespaces.  If you include the js file that contains the logic, you can access its properties.  We do stuff like this: `PortletBrowser.l18n.Buttons[0].caption = <%= Resources.GetStirng(..) %>`.  Then in the javascript you access them. Collisions don't occur because they're encapsulated within their relevant class.